# React with TypeScript: How to type a Component in a Library? (Part 1)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

In a codebase I am working on we are extracting components which should work in a generic way (because we want to put them into a separate npm package eventually).

[Running Example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/adoring-austin-wrq7t9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx)

For example, we have the following `Form` component in React which uses `any` at two places. It should somehow behave in a generic way here (or derive the types from the given `props`):

```
// THIS SHOULD BE LIKE A FORM THAT WE CANNOT TOUCH
// BECAUSE IT COMES FROM A LIBRARY
// SO HOW TO TYPE IT PROPERLY?

import * as React from "react";

type FORM_ELEMENT_TYPE = "textfield" | "numberfield";

export type FormElement = {
  key: string;
  label: string;
  type: FORM_ELEMENT_TYPE;
};

type FormProps = {
  formData?: any; // <- HOW TO TYPE IF formData CAN BE ANYTHING? PERHAPS WITH THE HELP OF formElements?
  formElements?: FormElement[];
  onChange: (form: any) => void; // <- HOW TO TYPE IF WE DO NOT KNOW THE FORM? WE KNOW THE formElements TO DERIVE THE OUTPUT FROM, NO?
};

const Form: React.FC<FormProps> = ({
  formData = {},
  formElements = [],
  onChange,
}) => {
  return (
    <form>
      {formElements.map((formElement) => {
        if (formElement.type === "textfield") {
          return (
            <label key={formElement.key}>
              {formElement.label}:
              <input
                type="text"
                value={formData[formElement.key]}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  onChange({
                    ...formData,
                    [formElement.key]: event.target.value,
                  })
                }
              />
            </label>
          );
        }

        if (formElement.type === "numberfield") {
          return (
            <label key={formElement.key}>
              {formElement.label}:
              <input
                type="number"
                value={formData[formElement.key]}
                onChange={(event) =>
                  onChange({
                    ...formData,
                    [formElement.key]: event.target.valueAsNumber,
                  })
                }
              />
            </label>
          );
        }

        return null;
      })}
    </form>
  );
};

export default Form;
```

The App component -- where we have control, because it's not a component in the library -- uses the Form component. Here we have the issue of not knowing about the type in the `onChange` event handler which our Form component uses:

```
import * as React from "react";

import Form, { FormElement } from "./Form";

const App = () => {
  const [formData, setFormData] = React.useState({
    name: "David",
    age: 20,
  });

  const formElements: FormElement[] = [
    {
      key: "name",
      label: "Name",
      type: "textfield",
    },
    {
      key: "age",
      label: "Age",
      type: "numberfield",
    },
  ];

  // IS THERE ANY WAY TO INFER THIS?  v
  const handleChange = (newFormData: any) => {
    setFormData(newFormData);
  };

  return (
    <Form
      formData={formData}
      formElements={formElements}
      onChange={handleChange}
    />
  );
};

export default App;
```

How can I type the Form and App components with generics or/and inference to always know about the correct types for all 3 places where `any` is used at the moment? For the sake of completeness, here a link to the [complete code as a running example](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/adoring-austin-wrq7t9?file=%2Fsrc%2FApp.tsx).

I'd like to hear readers' opinions on [Part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75445816/react-with-typescript-how-to-type-a-component-in-a-library-part-2) where the Form component gets a new prop called `customFormElements`.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit tricky. First I'll not concern myself with the implementation of `Form` and not care about type errors inside and just try to find a way to type `Form` so that when you use it from outside, the typings are correct.

There are two main ways to go when putting a generic here: you could either try to infer the value for `formData` given the value of `formElements`, or you could use the descriptions for fields from `formElements` and use them to infer the type of `formData`. The latter option probably makes more sense, so let's start with this one:

```
// I'll need this type later so I move it to enum
enum FormElementType {
  // I believe adding "field" suffix here is redundant, but you may return 
  // it if you'd like
  text = 'text',
  number = 'number',
}
// What values must be passed for field of each type
type FieldTypeMap = {
  [FormElementType.text]: string,
  [FormElementType.number]: number,
}

export type FormElement = {
  key: string;
  label: string;
  type: FormElementType;
};

// See explanation below
type FormProps<TElement extends FormElement> = {
  data: FormData<NoInfer<TElement>>;
  onChange: (form: FormData<NoInfer<TElement>>) => void;
  elements: readonly TElement[];
};

// Utility types
type NoInfer<T> = T extends any ? T : T;
type FormData<TElement extends FormElement> = {
    [Key in TElement["key"]]: 
      TElement extends infer U extends FormElement & {key: Key} 
        ? FieldTypeMap[U['type']]
        : never
}

export declare const Form: <TElement extends FormElement>({
  data,
  elements,
  onChange,
}: FormProps<TElement>) => JSX.Element;
```

So the generic argument acccepts a union of objects that describe form fields, like in your example

```
TElement = {
      key: "name",
      label: String,
      type: FormElementType.text,
    } | {
      key: "age",
      label: "Age",
      type: FormElementType.number,
    }
```

Then we use `FormData` type to extract the shape for `formData` object from this union. `TElement extends infer U extends FormElement & {key: Key}` will map over values of `TElement` union, find the one that has its `key` property equal to `Key` and assign it to `U`. Then we extract the value type for this field using `U['type']` field and a predefined mapping between value types and `FormElementType` values. Note: you need at least TS 4.8 for `infer ... extends ...` syntax to work.

The `NoInfer` thing is a trick that basically tells typescript that it must not infer the value for `TElement` generic argument from the places where it is wrapped into `NoInfer`. So when using `Form` typescript will only be allowed to infer `TElement` from the value of the `formElements` field, and not from `formData`.

Also I made `formData` and `onChange` required arguments, because I'm not sure what it means for them to be optional.

This approach works, but it's a bit awkward to use, because by default when defining an object with string values TS doesn't infer them as string literals but just as `string` values. Therefore you will have to add `as const` to `formElements`

```
const formElements = [
    {
      key: "name", // because of "as const" this is inferred as `"name"` and not as just `string`
      label: "Name",
      type: FormElementType.string,
    },
    {
      key: "age", // Similarly this is inferred to be `"age"` and not just `string`
      label: "Age",
      type: FormElementType.number,
    }
] as const

<Form
  elements={formElements}
  // ...
/>
```

When TS 5 is out, this might become less awkward, because you will be able to write `TElement extends const FormElement` or something.

Going the other way is also possible

```
type FormProps<TData extends {}> = {
  data: TData;
  onChange: (form: TData) => void;
  elements: FormElements<TData>;
};

type ElementType<T> =
  // You neeed to manually check for all possible `T` types here and infer what the values for `type` in `formElements` might be
  T extends string ? FormElementType.text : 
    T extends number ? FormElementType.number : never
type FormElements<TData extends {}> = ReadonlyArray<{
  [key in keyof TData]: {
    key: key,
    label: string,
    type: ElementType<TData[key]>
  }
}[keyof TData]>

export declare const Form: <TData extends {} extends {}>({
  data,
  elements,
  onChange,
}: FormProps<TData>) => JSX.Element;
```

This way you don't need to use `as const` but *only when passing `formElements` to `Form` inline*:

```
<Form
  elements={[
    {
      key: "name",
      label: "Name",
      type: FormElementType.string,
    },
    {
      key: "age",
      label: "Age",
      type: FormElementType.number,
    }
  ]}
  // ...
/>
```

And this is also very awkward, because if you use wrong types you will get an error on `formElements` and not on `formData` field which is confusing and weird.

One way how to get rid of having to use this `as const` I can think of is the following: if you can change your API so that you use an object of `formElements` and not an array, then we can make typescript infer `key` names from this object keys. Moreover if instead of `FormElementType` being an enum, you make it an object with literal properties, you can use its values to better infer the value of the `type` field. Something like this:

```
export type FormElementType =
  (typeof FormElementType)[keyof typeof FormElementType];
export const FormElementType = {
  text: 'text',
  number: 'number',
} as const;

type FieldTypeMap = {
  [FormElementType.text]: string;
  [FormElementType.number]: number;
};

export type FormElement = {
  label: string;
  type: FormElementType;
};

// See explanation below
type FormProps<TElements extends Record<string, FormElement>> = {
  data: FormData<NoInfer<TElements>>;
  onChange: (form: FormData<NoInfer<TElements>>) => void;
  elements: TElements;
};

// Utility types
type NoInfer<T> = T extends any ? T : T;
type FormData<TElements extends Record<string, FormElement>> = {
  [Key in keyof TElements]: FieldTypeMap[TElements[Key]["type"]];
};

export declare const Form: <TElements extends Record<string, FormElement>>({
  data,
  elements,
  onChange,
}: FormProps<TElements>) => JSX.Element;
```

And use it like this:

```
const formElements = {
      name: {
          label: "Name",
          type: FormElementType.text,
      },
      age: {
          label: "Age",
          type: FormElementType.number,
      },
}

<Form
    data={formData}
    elements={formElements}
    onChange={handleChange}
/>
```

Now speaking about the implementation of `Form`, I don't think you can get away and not see any errors inside `Form` if you use such complicated types, so honestly good luck typing it. I think it's mostly just easier to use type casts, or to not type it very meticulously at all, and just move these complex typings to a separate declaration file, where they will be visible from outside, and not interfere with implementation in your npm package.

I didn't write a full working implementation of this form, but here were some ideas you may find useful to type this mess. Forms are hard